Tkinter label limit number of rows?
I am using wraplength to limit the number of characters on each line for a label. Is there a way I can also limit the number of rows the label can have? I would like it to have a maximum of 2 rows of text.

I have tried setting the height however this doesn't seem to do anything.
Here is the relevant code:
self.nowplayingsong = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit tellus", fg_color="transparent", font=("Arial", 100), anchor="w", justify='left', wraplength=700)
        self.nowplayingsong.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100, pady=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W")


I don't think you can do this with a Label.  Possibly you could use a Text, with height=2 - set its state to "disabled" after you have inserted your text.

Label widget without wrapping the text; you can use the maxlines.

I'm pretty sure in Tkinter and also in customtkinter, there is no direct way to limit the number of lines in a Label widget.
However, you could control the number of displayed lines by using a Text widget.
A Text widget should offer more control over the display of text and could be used to limit the number of lines.
You can configure the Text widget to display only a specific number of lines by setting the height of the widget.
Here is an example of how you could use the Text widget:
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit tellus, dapibus in dolor et, tincidunt faucibus nunc. Etiam vehicula quam ac metus."
        max_lines = 2
        wraplength = 700
        
        limited_text = self.limit_text_to_max_lines(text, max_lines)
        
        self.text_widget = tk.Text(self, height=max_lines, wrap=tk.WORD, )
        self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, limited_text)
        self.text_widget.configure(state='disabled')  
        self.text_widget.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
        
    def limit_text_to_max_lines(self, text, max_lines):
        lines = text.split('\n')
        if len(lines) > max_lines:
            lines = lines[:max_lines]
            lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip() + "..."  
        return "\n".join(lines)

